# How do I get a batch variable to influence another variable?

Tags: batch-file

So right now I am trying to get a random number generator (which I have set to go from 1-4) to influence a variable. Here's what I have now:

```
set /A randomVariable=%RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %randomVariable%="1" set %name%="Jeff"
if %randomVariable%="2" set %name%="Bob"
if %randomVariable%="3" set %name%="Jerry"
if %randomVariable%="4" set %name%="Tom"
goto :advisory1
```

I really don't think that this code is right, could anyone help?

Comment: If you type `if /?` it will show you the correct syntax.

Comment: Two problems with your `IF` comparisons.  As @ACatInLove, pointed out you do have a syntax issue which you should be able to fix by reading the help file. Secondly, you have to realize that it is a TRUE string comparison. If you have quotes on one side of the comparison they have to be on the other side of the comparison for the statement to be true.  This has been covered dozens and dozens of times on StackOverFlow.  You should consider searching StackOverFlow or Google first before asking your questions. You also have the wrong syntax for your `SET`  command.  Read that help file as well.

Comment: Here is another option for your random. `set /A randomVariable=%RANDOM% %% 4 + 1`

Comment: In fact, you don't even need to **`+ 1`**, _just use 0..3 for Jeff..Tom_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close with this one.  You just need to change the `if` comparisons a bit.

1. Use the comparison operator `==` rather than the set operator `=`.
2. Add quotes around `%randomVariable%` to avoid any errors that may come up if `randomVariable` fails to set for whatever reason.

It would look something like this:

```
set /A randomVariable=%RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if "%randomVariable%"=="1" set name="Jeff"
if "%randomVariable%"=="2" set name="Bob"
if "%randomVariable%"=="3" set name="Jerry"
if "%randomVariable%"=="4" set name="Tom"
goto :advisory1
```

Comment: I will disagree with you on removing the quotes. It is always safe to use quotes as long as you use them on both sides of the comparison. It also protects again empty variables.  If for some reason the randomvariable is not set it will expand to nothing and then you will get a syntax error with the IF command because there is nothing on the left side of the comparison.

Comment: That's a really good point.  Thankfully, it's a pretty simple change, I'll update the solution.  Thanks!